# Reduce sql Query execution time from 3.349s

Tags: mysql, query-performance

This query is working perfectly but uses 3.3493s to execute, please help me check through it to see if there is a way to better optimize it.

```
SELECT u.ID, 
(SELECT meta_value FROM wpcg_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'first_name' AND user_id = u.ID ) AS firstname, 
(SELECT meta_value FROM wpcg_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'last_name' AND user_id = u.ID ) AS lastname, 
(SELECT meta_value FROM wpcg_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'user_avatar_thumb' AND user_id = u.ID ) AS avatarurl, 
(SELECT COUNT(m.user_id) FROM wpcg_usermeta AS m , wpcg_users AS uz  WHERE m.user_id = uz.ID AND m.meta_key = 'user_parent' AND m.meta_value = u.ID AND u.user_registered BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()) AS referral_users 
FROM wpcg_users AS u 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT( user_id ) FROM wpcg_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'user_parent' AND meta_value = u.ID ) > 0 
ORDER BY referral_users DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about your database scheme?

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)
 

MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: it is a wordpress database, so when i use the date interval filter in  referral_users the querry take long time to execute, from my research, i saw something about adding index to for optimization, but not so clear

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Please edit clarifications into posts, not comments.

Comment: Juan's link includes a section aimed at how to improve on the inefficiencies of WP's `wp_postmeta`; it may apply to your `wpcg_usermeta`.  If so, now much does it help?  And, let's see your schema.

Answer (score 1):

Consider restructuring your query

```
Select col1, col2, col3, ...

FROM wpcg_users AS u 
JOIN wpcg_usermeta m on u.ID = m.user_id
where meta_key in ('first_name', 'last_name', ...)
```

You have a number of subqueries which can be eliminated through re-structuring the query which can improve performance.  When you have a sub query like this in the select it is run for every row.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, provide meta of used table and type of database- columns, indexes, type of tables and etc (its look like as MySql, but its may be false). Try split this request on some simple requests. Then try to get statistics about each requests. 
Also try reduce calls to some table, doing nested sql-c.
Sorry for my English. I’m studying it at now)